# How to implement advert placement base on time for a period of days

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a complicated feature on a project. The feature is to display advert best on time for particular hours in a day within a particular days. Let say I have 20 ad in my database, 4 are to display for 1hr each day for 14days. And 6 are to display for 3hrs each day for 24days. and 10 are to display for 6hrs each day for 30days.

Since the admin is the person that will create plan for it, I have a table that handle that with this columns:

ad_plans:

```
 $table->string('ad_type');
 $table->string('duration');
 $table->string('display_time');
 $table->string('amount');
```

Now each  ad_placement belongs to a plan above, so I have this in the ad_placements table:

```
$table->string('ad_plan_id');
$table->string('title');
$table->string('image');
$table->string('description');
$table->string('url');
$table->string('time_end')->nullable();
$table->string('duration_end')->nullable();
$table->enum('is_approve', ['Approved', 'Pending'])->default('Pending');
$table->string('view')->nullable();
```

Having configure the relationship, the create plan and placement is working. where I'm stock is how to display those data from database best on time for a particular hours in specify days.

Pls friends help me out, I'm off with logics on how to implement it.

Comment: do you want to show all the ads in one day? e.g 1hr for the first day, after that, do you want to show 3hrs and 6hrs ads on the same day? or after 14days 3hrs ad will start showing?

Comment: What is the meaning of display_time, amount and duration? You need to get your `ad_plans` that are available and for those you need to get the `ad_placements.time_end <= now()`. This should list all adds to be displayed and if you loop through them you can check the times to display.

Comment: @sibabratswain yes

Comment: @Florian display_time is the time inwhich ad will last, e.g 1hr or 2hrs, etc. duration is how many days ad will last, e.g, 20days, 26days etc. amount; each ad plan has a price tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php is a server based technology and is not time aware

If you want to make it time aware, you have two options:

- use Crontab (or the windows equivalent)
- use a frontend script (javascript or another)

My suggestion would be to write a getAdsForDateTime(DateTime $datetime) function that will query your database for the ads to be displayed at a given moment.

This function would be called by your chosen (and time aware) method on the specifications required for your app